# Как обернуть вторую строку тэгами при помощи regex?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько строк:

```html
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
```

Желаемый результат:

```html
String1
<strong>String2</strong>
String3
String4
String5
```

Comment: Regex не предназначен для таких вещей. Вы слишком  переоцениваете его возможности. Быть может двумя regex такое получится. Одним - врядли. Но, при реализации обычными строковыми функциями, либо массивами - реализация будет работать в разы быстрее, плюс проще в понимании и реализации.

Comment: @nick_n_a, хотел делать это заменой в notepad

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = `String1
String2
String3
String4
String5`;

console.log(str.replace(/(?<=^.*\s?\n)(.*)/, '<strong>$1</strong>'));
```

https://regex101.com/r/y2Ajps/1